# Conditional if statement inside options

Tags: c#

I am making a screen recorder app I need to add a conditional function inside the options parameters where if RecordFullscreen is active ignore the SourceRect.
Using C# Winforms framework 4.78

```
 RecorderOptions options = new RecorderOptions
            {
                AudioOptions = new AudioOptions
                {
                    //Bitrate = AudioBitrate.bitrate_128kbps,
                    //Channels = AudioChannels.Stereo,
                    IsAudioEnabled = true,
                    IsOutputDeviceEnabled = SpeakersOn,
                    IsInputDeviceEnabled = MicrophoneOn,
                    AudioOutputDevice = selectedOutputDevice.DeviceName,
                    AudioInputDevice = selectedInputDevice.DeviceName,
                    InputVolume = 1,
                    OutputVolume = 1,
                },
            OutputOptions = new OutputOptions
                {
                    RecorderMode = RecorderMode.Video,
                    //This sets a custom size of the video output, in pixels.
                    OutputFrameSize = new ScreenSize(1920, 1080),
                    //Stretch controls how the resizing is done, if the new aspect ratio differs.
                    Stretch = StretchMode.Uniform,

                    //condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false
                    //!RecordFullscreen ? => SourceRect = new ScreenRect(this.Left + 15, this.Top + 35, this.Width - 30, this.Height - 50)

                    //if not RecordFullscreen use SourceRect else ignore SourceRect 
                    SourceRect = new ScreenRect(this.Left + 15, this.Top + 35, this.Width - 30, this.Height - 50)
                },
            };
```

Comment: I believe you need this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator

Comment: A reference to solve the issue helps but the actual usage in code is way to learn. The biggest issue I have is terminology using answer below had I known I needed the ternary-operator I most likely could have googled the answer. Thanks anyway. A not so good answer is better than none.

Answer (score 3):

Use a [ternary-operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) and use whatever `SourceRect`s-default-value evaluates to (probably `null` for a (nullable) reference-type).

```
OutputOptions = new OutputOptions
{
    RecorderMode = RecorderMode.Video,
    SourceRect = RecordFullscreen ? 
        null : // or whatever is the correct default-value here
        new ScreenRect(this.Left + 15, this.Top + 35, this.Width - 30, this.Height - 50)            
}
```

Be aware that I flipped the condition, as it's easier to read, IMHO.

An alternative would be to omit the property from the object-initializer and set it afterwards:

```
RecorderOptions options = new RecorderOptions
{
    AudioOptions = new AudioOptions { ... },
    OutputOptions = new OutputOptions
    {
        RecorderMode = RecorderMode.Video,
        ...        
    }
};

if(RecordFullscreen)
{
    options.OutputOptions.SourceRect
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this work as expected. I truly appreciate your time and answer.

Comment: Actually I was curious of how actually to add a if statement I didn't realize I could just add it afterwards as in your second post. If I could upvote it again I would. Again your positivity in my situation is a wonderful and truly appreciated.